# How can I center an avatar in ionic 3?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

How can I center an ion-avatar horizontally like in this picture?

Or how can I add a centered image to a ion-row and add an avatar style to the image?

[image: centered avatar]

Comment: Can you show the `html` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a [CSS Utility attribute](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#responsive-text-attributes) you can use called `text-center`.
Apply that to a div, that wraps your image.
`text-center` on the div would resolve to the CSS

div {
 text-align: center!important;
}
Style it with a class or id, if you've got many in your markup.

You might want to also apply something like this to the image to style it..

```css
#imgwrap {
min-width:200px;
min-height:150px;
background-color:blue;
text-align: center!important;
  img {
  border:0;
  max-width:140px;
  border-radius:50%;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class"split-pane">
<div id="imgwrap">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Tricks has some content if you want run into [issues with border radius and images](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/).